# Декомпиляция kotlin проекта скомпилированного в .jar

Tags: kotlin, jvm

Как получить исходный код kotlin проекта скомпилированного в .jar файл?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca). Есть версии под любую ОС, простая в использовании. С помощью этой программы можно открыть jar-архив и поизучать декомпилированный код.

Kotlin-код вы, конечно, не получите, но сможете посмотреть соответствующий java-код.